# Multiply value of two columns and make overal sum with awk and POSIX shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, posix

I want to multiply the values of two columns and add the result of that to the overall sum.

I am working with logs in this format:

```
2021-07-29 22:51:55;PG;sell;138.60;USD;3198;65fb482a-7943-11eb-9378-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:01:30;MSFT;sell;237.64;USD;1424;65fb4938-7943-11eb-9674-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:01:47;TSLA;sell;707.03;USD;1578;65fb4a50-7943-11eb-9f6e-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:05:42;GOOGL;buy;1990.04;USD;6185;65fb4b5e-7943-11eb-87f6-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:08:43;GOOG;buy;1975.97;USD;9281;65fb4c76-7943-11eb-8023-8c85906a186d
2021-07-29 23:13:13;UNH;sell;321.06;USD;8351;65fb4d8e-7943-11eb-9ba5-8c85906a186d
```

I want to calculate the values for sell and buy stocks. I am working in a POSIX shell with awk:

```
SELL=$(echo "$INPUT" | awk -F ';' '$3 == "sell" { sum += $4 * $6 }  END {print sum}')
BUY=$(echo "$INPUT" | awk -F ';' '$3 == "buy" { sum += $4 * $6 } END {print sum}')
```

This works for addition only like this:

```
SELL=$(echo "$INPUT" | awk -F ';' '$3 == "sell" { sum += $4 } END {print sum}')
```

But with the multiplication, I get this error: (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: This works fine with GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: It will work fine in any awk. You've shown us an apparently stripped-down error message devoid of the usual context that would accompany such a message plus a few scripts which cannot produce that error message. Show us an actual [mcve] that produces that error message if you'd like help to debug it.

Comment: with respect to `echo "$INPUT" | ....` - reading all your input into a variable is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @EdMorton as the error I got wasn't very specific I didn't think, that bc was the problem because it worked with different inputs. I am reading the input from the log file to a variable because I can't use any temporary files to store it in nor can I change the file. I am open to a better solution tho as I am new to shell (couple of weeks).

Comment: Just have an awk script run on your log file, no need to read the file into a variable or copy it or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in awk using scientific number notation which is not compatible with bc word operations.

The trick was in forcing awk to use classical float notation with printf:

```
SELL=$(echo "$INPUT" | awk -F ';' '$3 == "sell" { sum += $4 * $6 }  END {printf "%.2f", sum}')
BUY=$(echo "$INPUT" | awk -F ';' '$3 == "buy" { sum += $4 * $6 } END {printf "%.2f", sum}')
OUTPUT=$(echo "$SELL - $BUY" | bc)
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

With hints from everyone in mind the clearly better version of this is:

```
OUT=$(echo "$FILTERED_INPUT" | awk -F ';' '{
   if ($3 == "sell")
     { v_sell += $4 * $6 }
   else if ($3 == "buy")
     { v_buy+= $4 * $6 } }
   END {printf "%.2f", v_sell - v_buy} }')
echo "$OUT"
```

Comment: Using 2 calls to `awk` plus 1 to `bc` instead of just having `awk` do everything you need in a single call is a bad approach.

Comment: @EdMorton as a shell newbie I will refactor the code later. the purpose of this solely to get things running, but I agree with you 100%.

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to create/destroy files and processes with a language to sequence calls to tools. It is not a tool to manipulate text (including do math). The guys who invented shell also invented awk as one of the tools for shell to call when it needs to manipulate text. Your shell script calling awk multiple times should simply be one awk script.